# Convert string date of PST format NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to convert `@"2016-04-15T15:00:00-07:00"` to `NSDate` in objective C. I am using the `NSdateFormatter` `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"` but not getting the `NSDate`

I have to make the string date from server to PST time NSDate

Code :

```
NSString *strDate = @"2016-04-15T22:00:00Z";

NSDate* ts_utc;

NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[df_utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

ts_utc = [df_utc dateFromString:strDate];



NSDateFormatter* df_local = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df_local setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"]];
[df_local setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

NSString* ts_local_string = [df_local stringFromDate:ts_utc];


NSDate *date = [df_local dateFromString:ts_local_string];
```

Please suggest.

Comment: @trojanfoe - code updated

Comment: Make sure your locale is set to English otherwise you will have problems with the time zone names on non-English locales. Neither `UTC` or `PST` are standardized names.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works correctly for me so I am pretty sure that the problem is in your expectations, not in your code. Note that `NSDate` is an instance of time which is independent on time zones. Only string representations of a date depend on time zones.

Comment: Your question and code don't match. You say you want to parse a date string in the format of `@"2016-04-15T15:00:00-07:00"` but the code you posted shows a date string in the format `@"2016-04-15T22:00:00Z"`. Those are not the same format. The timezone format is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I had the same problem as you and I solved it in that way

```
NSString *strDate = @"2016-04-15T22:00:00Z";
NSDate* ts_utc;
NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[df_utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
ts_utc = [df_utc dateFromString:strDate];

NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"];
NSInteger timeZoneHourOffset = (NSInteger) ([destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:ts_utc] / 3600.0); //geting the time offset between UTC and PST
NSDate *pstDate = [ts_utc dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneHourOffset * 60 * 60]; //applying that offset into ts_utc NSDate
```

Hope, this will hep you !

Comment: Shouldn't that be `'Z'` (i.e. quoted)?

Comment: I want the date in PST time zone. Not UTC

Comment: @NiKKi Yes but you have a literal `Z` at the end of the date string, which shows it's "zulu" (UTC).  How you convert it to PST internally has got nothing to do with the parsing from string to `NSDate`.

Comment: @trojanfoe in my above code, at line `NSString* ts_local_string = [df_local stringFromDate:ts_utc];` I get the string date in PST which is `@"2016-04-15T15:00:00-07:00"` . That is not getting conberted in PST NSDate format

Comment: How result should look like from `2016-04-15T22:00:00Z` in PST time zone format?

Comment: @k8mil `2016-04-15T15:00:00` which is 7 hours difference